# How do I reinstall everything Ubuntu related software on my system?

Tags: apt, apache2

Yesterday, I was tired and I did something pretty stupid. Apache wasn't working, so I decided to reinstall everything related to `apache2`. So I began by removing `apache2` and then did the following:

`sudo apt-get remove libapr*`

After this, everything that depended on `libapr*` was erased, including `apt`, the Software Center, several Python stuff, Transmission...

How do I get everything back? Especially `apt`...

Comment: Your system might be too broken to install any software on it, as it's likely that your system has no working package managers. It may be easier to reinstall the whole system if you have backups. Could you confirm whether `synaptic` or `aptitiude` work in your system (please note that neither of them is no longer installed by default in Ubuntu 13.04)?

Answer (score 0):

oops! have you still got the LiveCD that you used to install Ubuntu in the first place?

If so, insert the CD in to the drive and reboot.

When liveCD loads, click install. You should be offered the choice of repairing or reinstalling.